# Wildfly/JBoss CLI: How can I set a variable to the result of an expression?

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly, jboss-cli

I have an expression that reads the user-name attribute of a datasource:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MYDATASOURCE:read-attribute(name=user-name)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "DS_USERNAME"
}
```

I would like to store that result in a variable, so that I can use it in other expressions.

If I simply use *set*, it will set the variable as the expression itself, rather than the result:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] set DSUSER=/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MYDATASOURCE:read-attribute(name=user-name)
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] echo $DSUSER
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MYDATASOURCE:read-attribute(name=user-name)

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] $DSUSER
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "DS_USERNAME"
}
```

I really just want to set DSUSER somehow, such that 'echo $DSUSER' results in 'DS_USERNAME':

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] echo $DSUSER
DS_USERNAME
```

Is there any way I could do that?
(I've tried piping it to grep, but this grep doesn't support regex capture groups)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do it using backticks (`) like:

```
set DSUSER=`/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MYDATASOURCE:read-attribute(name=user-name)`
```